# Get the file size in android sdk?

Tags: java, android, file

I have a problem getting the size of a file. I have the following code:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/lala.txt");
long length = file.length();
```

And always length is zero, yes zero.

I am using Android SDK (not sure what version), the code is running inside an Activity, I have created an sdcard.

Perhaps it is a permission issue? Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 92):

The `File.length()` method returns the following [according to the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--):

> *"The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes."*

As you can see, zero can be returned:

- if the file exists but contained zero bytes.
- if the file does not exist, or
- if the file is some OS-specific special file.

My money is on the second case; i.e. that you have the wrong filename / pathname.  Try calling `File.exists()` on the filename to see what that tells you.  The other two cases are possible too, I guess.

(For the record, most `/proc/...` files on a Linux-based system also have an apparent file size of zero.  And Android is Linux based.)

Answer (score 33):

If you want to get the folder/file size in terms of **Kb** or **Mb** then use the following code. It will help in finding the accurate size of your file.

```
public static String getFolderSizeLabel(File file) {
    long size = getFolderSize(file) / 1024; // Get size and convert bytes into Kb.
    if (size >= 1024) {
        return (size / 1024) + " Mb";
    } else {
        return size + " Kb";
    }
}
```

This function will return size in form of bytes:

```
public static long getFolderSize(File file) {
    long size = 0;
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles()) {    
            size += getFolderSize(child);
        }
    } else {
        size = file.length();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should use:

```
File file = new File(Uri.parse("/sdcard/lala.txt").getPath());
```

instead of:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/lala.txt");
```

Comment: I can't see "uri.toString()" in the question. 'new File("/sdcard/lala.txt")' is okay if you know the path is right.

Comment: Why would this make any difference?  `"/sdcard/lala.txt"` is a pathname ... not a URL.

Comment: @Stephen C URI != URL

Comment: Yes, I know that.  That's why I said URL.   Please try to understand what I am actually saying in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use the following code instead of hard-coding the path ("/sdcard/lala.txt"):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/lala.txt");
file.length()
```

Answer (score -1):

### Kotlin Extension Solution

The first thing you should do with the file is confirm that it exists:

```
val File?.exists get() = this?.exists() ?: false
```

If you need a File from a String or Uri, try adding these to make working with them more declarative:

```
fun Uri.asFile(): File = File(toString())

fun String?.asUri(): Uri? {
    try {
        return Uri.parse(this)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
    return null
}
```

**For reading actual filesize,** add these somewhere, then call `myFile.sizeInMb` or whichever you need

```
val File.size get() = if (!exists()) 0.0 else length().toDouble()
val File.sizeInKb get() = size / 1024
val File.sizeInMb get() = sizeInKb / 1024
val File.sizeInGb get() = sizeInMb / 1024
val File.sizeInTb get() = sizeInGb / 1024
```

If you'd like to easily display the values as a string, these are simple wrappers. Feel free to customize the default decimals displayed

```
fun File.sizeStr(): String = size.toString()
fun File.sizeStrInKb(decimals: Int = 0): String = "%.${decimals}f".format(sizeInKb)
fun File.sizeStrInMb(decimals: Int = 0): String = "%.${decimals}f".format(sizeInMb)
fun File.sizeStrInGb(decimals: Int = 0): String = "%.${decimals}f".format(sizeInGb)

fun File.sizeStrWithBytes(): String = sizeStr() + "b"
fun File.sizeStrWithKb(decimals: Int = 0): String = sizeStrInKb(decimals) + "Kb"
fun File.sizeStrWithMb(decimals: Int = 0): String = sizeStrInMb(decimals) + "Mb"
fun File.sizeStrWithGb(decimals: Int = 0): String = sizeStrInGb(decimals) + "Gb"
```