# Size of text file

Tags: android

I have a text file in sd card , I want to get size of text file in mb programatically from my android application. How can I get size of text file in MB programatically?

Comment: file size is in bytes so when you need to convert it to MB just divid by 1024 twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
public long fileSizeInKb(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    long fileSize = file.length();
    return fileSize / 1024;                    
}
```

Let me know if you are still facing any issue.

Comment: Note that this snippet returns the file size in KB, not MB.

Answer (score 3):

Using [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.htm) class method [public long getTotalSpace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getTotalSpace%28%29)

And [public long length()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.htm)

Like,

```
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/temp.txt");
String size = readableFileSize(file.getTotalSpace()); // file.length() alternate
```

And method **readableFileSize()**

```
public String readableFileSize(long size) {
    if(size <= 0) return "0";
    final String[] units = new String[] { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
    int digitGroups = (int) (Math.log10(size)/Math.log10(1024));
    return new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#").format(size/Math.pow(1024, digitGroups)) + " " + units[digitGroups];
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using the sugested `readableFileSize()` method it does not check for the array index, so e.g. `readableFileSize((long) Math.pow(1024, 5))` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

you need to open a stream to the file and then check the size like this:

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "lala.txt");
long size = file.length();
```

for more on this try reading here: [Get the file size in android sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7131930/1056359)