# How to get size of image in android studio?

Tags: java, android, file, filesize

I am unable to get the size of the image. Below is my code.

```
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dirM = new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/images.jpeg");
    Long length = dirM.length();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the file size in android sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131930/get-the-file-size-in-android-sdk)

Comment: You have just created a file with `new File(root.getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/images.jpeg");`. At this point there is no information about this file

Comment: I have an images.jpeg in /storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpeg ,but I don't get size of images.jpeg.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually fetching the length, not the size of the particular file. Use the below example to achieve what you want.

```
long imgSize = yourImageFileName.getAbsoluteFile().getTotalSpace();
```

Comment: What is yourImageFileName ?Is yourImageFileName  the address of the image ?

Comment: Thats the name of the image file(in code) you are trying to fetch details of. In your case I think its `dirM `.